# Ember backward compatibility

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, backwards-compatibility

I have a small ember-cli app written in 2.5.1 which I've been asked to integrate with a larger older ember app.

The older ember app is written with ember-cli 0.1.2.

I'm trying to find out the following:

1. What versions of ember are used with the different ember-cli versions (is it a 1:1 mapping?)
2. What major changes have been made between such disparate versions (I'm imagining a lot)
3. Whether I'm resigned to downgrading my newer app to an older version or whether I can drag the older app kicking and screaming up to date!

Any info or experiences suggesting approaches you've found useful would be great.

Comment: Check the ember version via the [ember-inspector](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector) back in 0.1 versions weren't on par

Comment: I think I managed to track down the client dependencies via bower and it seems to be using ember 1.7.9 which isn't quite as bad as I thought!

Comment: I m unsure if [ember-islands](https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-islands) might help you integrate the new in the old, try asking around on the slack channel

Comment: Generally there is no clear mapping between ember-cli and ember. You can use many ember versions with one ember-cli version and otherwise. Check the package.json and bower.json of the project to be clear.